# How to automatically removes orphans when merging a deserialized graph of objects in doctrine2?

Tags: orm, symfony, merge, doctrine-orm, orphan

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine2 to build a backend API. 
This API will receive graph of objects to CRUD in a database.

I'm using the great JMSSerializer bundle to deserialize the json-encoded graph of objects into detached a graph of detached entitied and then i'd like to simply merge that graph directly in the database.

In my code I have 2 entities : Parent and Child. There is a `OneToMany(cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)` relation defined in Parent.

In my database I have a Parent row with an id of 1, which has 3 children with ids 1,2,3.

I'd like to write something like (I'm not using the deserialization here, to simplify the example):

```
$parent = new Parent(); $parent->id = 1  // detached entity
$existing_child = new Child(); $child->id = 2 // detached entity
$new_child = new Child(); // new entity
$parent->addChild($existing_child);
$parent->addChild($new_child);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getEntityManager();
$em->merge($parent);

$em->flush();
```

Doing so, my new child is well created, and the existing child is updated but the old children (1 & 3) are not removed.

Can someone help me if I am missing something ?

Comment: We just ran into the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Nope, I ended up doing the merge by hand : iterating over my existing collection to remove or update elements, then add new ones.

Comment: I got a little confused. If you `addChild()` should there be also a function `removeChild()`?

Comment: That's the point, I just wanted to express the new state, and I wanted the system to compute what has changed since the old state (the removal)

Anyway I haven't done Symfony2 for several years now, but this question might help other people

Comment: So there is no function `removeChild()` ?! But where does the _detachment_ actually happened? For me it looks like the old children are still a property of its parent....

Comment: @goulashsoup feels true, @systho you should try to setting the old childrens parent id to `null`

Comment: Thanks for you comments. First, this question is from 2012 and I'm not currently waiting for an answer anymore :p. Secondly, "detached" is not about the parent<->child relationship but about the status with the entity manager. Those entities are detached because I've instanciated them using new and not using any EM mechanism :)

Comment: You can try $parent->getChild()->clear() before adding children to empty the array collection.